# Jakarta CDI force bean construction/register legacy event listeners

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a new Jakarta EE (Qurakus) application and some old code which has methods to register event listeners. I have made a wrapper for the event registry. Now I need some way to efficiently register a lot of event listeners. It looks something like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class EventRegistry {
    private Set<Listener<?>> listeners = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());

    public void register(Listener l) {
    }
    public void unregister(Listener l) {
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Listener1 implements Listener<MyEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(MyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

So basically I need a way for the listeners to register. I thought about using a Jakarta EE event which I trigger in PostConstruct of the registry and listen to it in each listener which then registers itself. Is this a save way to do it? Or will the listener bean be destructed if not used through an Inject? Also is there generally a better way to execute an operation for specific beans (I have all the listeners in a single package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do exactly what you want would be the following:

```java
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationScoped
public class EventRegistry {
    private final Set<Listener<?>> listeners = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());

    @Inject
    void init(Instance<Listener<?>> listenerInstance) {
        // check out the comments; for Quarkus you can inject all listeners as:
        // @Inject @All List<Listener<?>> listeners
        listenerInstance.forEach(listeners::add);
    }

    public void register(Listener l) { // maybe not even needed anymore
        listeners.add(l);
    }
}
```

You can ask CDI to do method injection; you can also ask it for an `Instance` of a type (in this case your `Listener`) and through the `Instance` retrieve all implementations, as shown above. Methods annotated with `@Inject` get called when injection happens on the instance and before any `@PostConstruct` methods. You could do property injection (i.e. `@Inject private Instance<Listener<?>> listenerInstance`), but you only need this object during the initialization of the `EventRegistry`. There is no reason to keep it around in a property for any longer.

Since you are in CDI and CDI supports the observer pattern you could consider changing your implementation to use that facility, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: This is correct CDI-wise. Since question mentions Quarkus specifically, you can also make use of `@Inject @All` utility which is documented here - https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#injecting-multiple-bean-instances-intuitively

Comment: Hey Siliarus, good pointer - I missed the Quarkus part! Thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered @Observes of CDI
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/enterprise/event/package-summary